# How can I connect Redmi K20 Pro back to my PC?

Tags: usb, miui, mtp, redmi

It was all fine before I removed windows 10 old folder from my system due to space problems from my c drive, I can connect easly my redmi phone through USB and it will show in explorer like a charm.  But now I cant connect my redmi phone through USB. Its not showing as drives as earlier. I can see it in device manger with driver error (yellow exclamation). I have been trying to get the driver back by searching google for the last two days and I failed and ended up in a mess. my phone are redmi Note 4, Redmi 4A, Redmi Note 7 Pro and Redmi K20 Pro. Can anyone help me with the correct driver to get  back my phones connected to PC. My PC is Lenova G50 with windows 10 Build 19041.vb_release.191206-1406. 64 bit os.

I am getting this while I try installing a pack which I recieved from web

[image]

Comment: For Windows, try downloading the OEM USB driver from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb).

Comment: Cross-posted to SU: https://superuser.com/q/1656702/356789